# How to access data from the createServer() method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a mock server which serves some json data. The server works correctly, but how can I access the data via fetch/axios? I am using fetch to fetch from the endpoint http://localhost:6000/users.

```
const http = require('http');
const json = require('./users.json');

const port = 6000;

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === '/users') {
    // Test error
    res.write(JSON.stringify(json)).end();
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404).end();
  }
}).listen(port, () => console.log(`Mock server listening on port ${port}`))
```

```
    const { data: usersData } = useFetch("http://localhost:6000/users")
```

Here is the hook

```
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const _fetch = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const json = await response.json();
                setData(json);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        };

        _fetch();
    }, [url]);

    return {
        data,
    };
};

export default useFetch;
```

I receive the below error message locally.

````
GET http://localhost:6000/users net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

useFetch.js?7d5b:38 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at _callee$ (useFetch.js?7d5b:22:1)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63:1)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:294:1)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:119:1)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?dbc6:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?dbc6:25:1)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?dbc6:32:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?dbc6:21:1)
    at _fetch (useFetch.js?7d5b:49:1)
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
const port = 6000;

useFetch("http://localhost:5500/users")
```

You're using two different port numbers, you should change one of them.

Comment: That was a typo. Now my port numbers are correct and still have an issue.